# How can I submit form from modal with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've spent days getting this far and I hope someone can help me on the final stretch. I have a form inside a modal that I wish to post to a php file with ajax. I'm a novice with jquery and I'm trying to figure out how to get these two bits of jquery to work together.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/k7FC2/1012/)

The Form and Modal

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-review="submit this information to database">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
        <p>some content</p>
        <input type="text" name="review" value=""/>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Jquery

```
//Variable is passed to modal
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var review = $(e.relatedTarget).data('review');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="review"]').val(review);
});

//Now post my form with the following ajax code when Modal Submit button is pressed.
$.post('insert.php', {review: review},
function(data){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $("#message").html(data);
    $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
    $("#message").fadeOut(2500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change type of button to `buttton` instead of submit and add an identifier so you can control the click using javascript click event, replace :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

by :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='submit-form'>Save changes</button>
```

And add click evetn to the button :

```
$('body').on('#submit-form', 'click', function(){
    var review = $('input[name="review"]').val();

    $.post('insert.php', {review: review},
        function(data){
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $("#message").html(data);
            $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
            $("#message").fadeOut(2500);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the modal-footer and modal-body inside the form tag.
Add id to submit button and then make ajax call.

```
  $("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(){

   //Ajax call here

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

please use the js code like this.

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
     var review = $(this).find("input[name=review]").val();

           var request = $.ajax({
           url: "insert.php",
           method: "POST",
           data: { review: review },
           dataType: "html"
        });
 })
```